# trouble getting a footnote in an abstract to show up

Tags: footnotes, amsart

I put a footnote at the end of the abstract but it doesn't show up at the bottom of the page. Here's a fragment of the TeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\title[Intrinsically justified reflection principles]{A proposed characterisation of the intrinsically justified reflection principles}

\author[$\mathrm{M^{\lowercase{c}}Callum}$ ]{\textbf{Rupert} $\mathbf{M^{\lowercase{c}}Callum}$ }

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
We are concerned with the distinction between intrinsic and extrinsic justifications for large-cardinal axioms, as outlined in for example Section 3 of \cite{Godel1964}. William Tait and Peter Koellner have examined the question of which reflection principles can be said to be intrinsically justified on the basis of the iterative conception of set. We formulate a new reflection principle which subsumes all of the reflection principles which which were considered by Tait and Koellner and are also known to be consistent, and which is itself consistent relative to an $\omega$-Erd\H{o}s cardinal. An open-ended family of strengthenings of this principle is tentatively proposed as exhausting everything that can be said to be intrinsically justified on the basis of the iterative conception of set. \footnote{The author was supported by the research grant DE 436/10-1 from Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft.}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and define `\newcommand{\McCallum}{M\textsuperscript{\MakeLowercase{c}}Callum}` in the preamble, so you can type your name as `\author{Rupert \McCallum}`

Comment: @touhami An answer?

Answer (score 1):

With `amsart.cls` the contents of the abstract environment is part of `maketitle` and one need to use `\thanks` instead of `\footnote`.

Instead of such acrobatics for typesetting your surname, doing

```
\newcommand{\McCallum}{M\textsuperscript{\MakeLowercase{c}}Callum}
```

and using `\McCallum{}` seems easier (the pair of braces is needed only if a space is to follow the name).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\McCallum}{M\textsuperscript{\MakeLowercase{c}}Callum}

\begin{document}

\title[Intrinsically justified reflection principles]{%
  A proposed characterisation of the intrinsically
  justified reflection principles%
}

\author[\McCallum]{\textbf{Rupert \McCallum}}
\thanks{The author was supported by the research grant DE 436/10-1
  from Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft.}

\begin{abstract}
We are concerned with the distinction between intrinsic and extrinsic 
justifications for large-cardinal axioms, as outlined in for example 
Section 3 of \cite{Godel1964}. William Tait and Peter Koellner have 
examined the question of which reflection principles can be said to 
be intrinsically justified on the basis of the iterative conception 
of set. We formulate a new reflection principle which subsumes all 
of the reflection principles which which were considered by Tait 
and Koellner and are also known to be consistent, and which is 
itself consistent relative to an $\omega$-Erd\H{o}s cardinal. 
An open-ended family of strengthenings of this principle is 
tentatively proposed as exhausting everything that can be said to 
be intrinsically justified on the basis of the iterative conception 
of set.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated my suggestion for streamlining the code and moved `\thanks` outside `abstract`, where it should belong.